# Getting git repository url with nodegit

Tags: node.js, nodegit

i'm using the nodegit library to get all commits from my repository, and i want to get general information from the local repository as for example:

- the url from the remote repository (Ex: https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is almost the same as you would do in git:

```
nodegit.Repository.open(".git").then(repo => {
    repo.config().then(config => {
        config.getStringBuf("remote.origin.url").then(buf => {
            console.log(buf.toString());
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the new APIs from `NodeGit@0.26.1`

```
export const getRemoteUrl = async (path, remoteName) => {
    try {
        const repository = await nodegit.Repository.open(path);
        const remote = await repository.getRemote(remoteName); // e.g. "origin"
        return await remote.url();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

// To use the above function within another async function:
const remoteUrl = await getRemoteUrl();
```